# How to set the same space in between frames in a whole Indesign document?

Tags: adobe-indesign

Is there a way to create the same space between image frames throughout a whole Indesign CC document. At the moment I have around 200 pages so it is quite tedious to do it page by page.

Comment: Are the frames already filled? You could configure a master page, apply it to other pages, then fill the frames on pages... but if the frames are *already* filled on 200 pages...well....

Answer (score 1):

I believe InDesign treats each page/spread as a separate object so you'll most likely, unfortunately, have to achieve this on a page by page basis. My suggestion would be to utilize ruler guide setups and copy/paste in place <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> (on Mac) across all of the pages where need to space your images. It'll be tedious for this project but in the future you could set up your document using Master Pages to ensure a consistent visual experience throughout it's entirety from the start. If you have the capability, there may be some creative scripting out there to carry out an action throughout the entire document but that's out of my skill set so I can't speak to that method.

Answer (score 0):

https://indesignsecrets.com/move-every-object-on-every-page-toward-or-away-from-spine.php

This script might do the trick? It will take a few passes I guess to get the frames where you want them, and/or possibly locking a layer that has the objects you don't want to move. Ive only used the script once before but it saved me from a similar situation (manually adjusting objects over and over).